# TypeError: expected string or buffer | Python

Tags: python, regex

I've been trying to parse a text file and manipulate it with regular expressions.
This is my script:

```
import re
original_file = open('jokes.txt', 'r+')
original_file.read()
original_file = re.sub("\d+\. ", "", original_file)
```

How to fix the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "filedisplay.py", line 4, in <module>
original_file = re.sub("\d+\. ", "", original_file)
File "C:\Python32\lib\re.py", line 167, in sub
return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

And why am I getting this error?

Comment: `original_file` is a file object, you need to read it to get its contents, or the buffer that the regex requires.

Comment: Thank you, I've updated the code and it still throws an error :/

Comment: Err, you didn't put the buffer in the variable `original_file`, so you're still using a file object in the regex. Why don't you use another variable? Like `contents = original_file.read()`?

Comment: That solved the problem... (Newbie here!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`original_file` is a file object, you need to [read](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.read) it to get its contents, or the buffer that the regex requires.

Usually, it's also good that you use `with` (just so you don't have to remember closing the file), so you might end up with something like this:

```
import re

with open('jokes.txt', 'r+') as original_file:
    contents = original_file.read()
    new_contents = re.sub(r"\d+\. ", "", contents)
```

You will see I rawed the regex string up there in the code (I used an `r` before the regex string). That's also a good practice, because sometimes you will have to double escape some characters for them to behave properly as you expect them.

Comment: This is explanatory... Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You call `original_file.read()`, but you don't assign that value to anything.

```
>>> original_file = open('test.txt', 'r+')
>>> original_file.read()
'Hello StackOverflow,\n\nThis is a test!\n\nRegards,\naj8uppal\n'
>>> print original_file
<open file 'test.txt', mode 'r+' at 0x1004bd250>
>>>
```

Therefore, you need to assign `original_file = original_file.read()`:

```
import re
original_file = open('jokes.txt', 'r+')
original_file = original_file.read()
original_file = re.sub("\d+\. ", "", original_file)
```

I would also suggest using `with` like @Jerry, so that you don't have to close the file to save the writing.